# Evernote Android SDK timeout

Tags: android, exception, sdk, timeout, evernote

I am using Evernote Android SDK for our application. When I am trying to upload note with attachment around 10 Mb, I receive the following exception:

> java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout (java.net.SocketException:
>   Socket is closed)

I am using `createNoteAsync` method with `onSuccess()` and `onException()` handlers. When we are using Evernote iOS SDK, everything goes fine.

What can be the problem?

P.S:  Files of smaller size are uploaded normally. Here is the Exception log:

```
com.evernote.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout at com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TAndroidTransport.flush(TAndroidTransport.java:136)
at com.evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore$Client.send_createNote(NoteStore.java:1751)
            at com.evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore$Client.createNote(NoteStore.java:1739)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteNoteStoreClient.createNote(EvernoteNoteStoreClient.java:557)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteNoteStoreClient$38.call(EvernoteNoteStoreClient.java:564)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteNoteStoreClient$38.call(EvernoteNoteStoreClient.java:561)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteAsyncClient$1.call(EvernoteAsyncClient.java:35)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.io.InterruptedIOException: timeout
            at okio.AsyncTimeout.exit(AsyncTimeout.java:258)
            at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:158)
            at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
            at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:46)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSink.write(HttpConnection.java:339)
            at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
            at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:96)
            at com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TAndroidTransport$1.writeTo(TAndroidTransport.java:112)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:898)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:760)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:274)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:230)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:201)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:81)
            at com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TAndroidTransport.flush(TAndroidTransport.java:127)
            at com.evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore$Client.send_createNote(NoteStore.java:1751)
            at com.evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore$Client.createNote(NoteStore.java:1739)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteNoteStoreClient.createNote(EvernoteNoteStoreClient.java:557)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteNoteStoreClient$38.call(EvernoteNoteStoreClient.java:564)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteNoteStoreClient$38.call(EvernoteNoteStoreClient.java:561)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteAsyncClient$1.call(EvernoteAsyncClient.java:35)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
            at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.checkOpen(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:238)
            at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.access$100(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:63)
            at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLOutputStream.write(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:726)
            at okio.Okio$1.write(Okio.java:78)
            at okio.AsyncTimeout$1.write(AsyncTimeout.java:155)
            at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
            at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:46)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSink.write(HttpConnection.java:339)
            at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
            at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:96)
            at com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TAndroidTransport$1.writeTo(TAndroidTransport.java:112)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:898)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:760)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:274)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:230)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:201)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:81)
            at com.evernote.client.conn.mobile.TAndroidTransport.flush(TAndroidTransport.java:127)
            at com.evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore$Client.send_createNote(NoteStore.java:1751)
            at com.evernote.edam.notestore.NoteStore$Client.createNote(NoteStore.java:1739)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteNoteStoreClient.createNote(EvernoteNoteStoreClient.java:557)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteNoteStoreClient$38.call(EvernoteNoteStoreClient.java:564)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteNoteStoreClient$38.call(EvernoteNoteStoreClient.java:561)
            at com.evernote.client.android.asyncclient.EvernoteAsyncClient$1.call(EvernoteAsyncClient.java:35)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```